# What is the reason of Host 'host_name' is blocked in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

When I use incorrect password to connect to mysql server, and the test count is over the `max_connect_errors`, and I find the `Aborted_connects` is also arise as the count I test, but the host is still not blocked.

So does the `Aborted_connects` over the `max_connect_errors` then host_name is blocked?

Answer (score 8):

At this point, you may need to run [**FLUSH HOSTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html) and see if this unblocks.

The MySQL Documentation says this about FLUSH HOSTS:

> - Empties the host cache tables. You should flush the host tables if
>     some of your hosts change IP address or if you get the error message
>     Host 'host_name' is blocked. When more than max_connect_errors errors
>     occur successively for a given host while connecting to the MySQL
>     server, MySQL assumes that something is wrong and blocks the host from
>     further connection requests. Flushing the host tables enables further
>     connection attempts from the host. See Section C.5.2.6, “Host
>     'host_name' is blocked”. You can start mysqld with
>     --max_connect_errors=999999999 to avoid this error message.

Why should a host get blocked to begin with ??

According to the [**MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blocked-host.html):

> If you get the following error, it means that mysqld has received many
>   connect requests from the host 'host_name' that have been interrupted
>   in the middle:  Host 'host_name' is blocked because of many connection
>   errors. Unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'   The number of
>   interrupted connect requests permitted is determined by the value of
>   the max_connect_errors system variable. After max_connect_errors
>   failed requests, mysqld assumes that something is wrong (for example,
>   that someone is trying to break in), and blocks the host from further
>   connections until you execute a mysqladmin flush-hosts command or
>   issue a FLUSH HOSTS statement. See Section 5.1.3, “Server System
>   Variables”.
>
> By default, mysqld blocks a host after 10 connection errors. You can
>   adjust the value by starting the server like this:

```
shell> mysqld_safe --max_connect_errors=10000 &
```

> If you get this error message for a given host, you should first
>   verify that there isn't anything wrong with TCP/IP connections from
>   that host. If you are having network problems, it does you no good to
>   increase the value of the max_connect_errors variable.

Comment: It doesn't look like these errors go to the normal MySQL error log. Is there a way to see a log of host-blocking connection errors? Also I noted the "successively" above. So, just need a successful connection in between? Or, should I just ask a new question?

Answer (score 2):

One cause of such a blockage is where some random person on the host decides to do some monitoring of MySQL and sets up a telnet to the MySQL port on the remote server. With a sufficient number of telnet invocations, the host is then blocked from further access to that MySQL server.
Unlike some servers, MySQL does not automatically unblock access after a reasonable amount of time: the server administrator has to knock MySQL on the head.

Comment: Still true 8.0.23

Answer (score 0):

For what's it worth, to diagnose this issue, you can try running

```
select * from performance_schema.host_cache
```

The table should be availabe starting with 5.6. More info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/host-cache.html). For example higher number of errors in `COUNT_MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR_ERRORS` vs `COUNT_SSL_ERRORS` may give you hint.

> 5.1.11.2 DNS Lookups and the Host Cache The MySQL server maintains an in-memory host cache that contains information about clients: IP
> address, host name, and error information. The Performance Schema
> host_cache table exposes the contents of the host cache so that it can
> be examined using SELECT statements. This may help you diagnose the
> causes of connection problems. [See Section 22.12.10.1, “The host_cache
> Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-host-cache-table.html)”.